# Nested if-else behaviour without braces

Tags: java, if-statement, syntax

Consider the following unformatted nested `if-else` Java code

```
if (condition 1)
if (condition 2)
action 1;
else
action 2;
```

My question is: according to the Java language specifications, to what if does the `else` branch apply?

By hand-reformatting and adding braces, which of these two is correct?

Block 1:

```
if (condition 1) {
    if (condition 2) {
        action 1;
    } else
        action 2;
    }
}
```

Block 2:

```
if (condition 1) {
    if (condition 2) {
        action 1;
    }
}
else {
    action 2;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: ... and why would you ever write that without the braces?

Comment: We write programs for humans to understand, always write if else statements with braces

Comment: @PrasadKharkar upvoted. My question is for curiosity about Java language specifications. Should I have added a "curiosity" tag?

Comment: neglecting braces is a very bad idea and by finding yourself asking this question you do know now *exactly* why!

Comment: I agree with the above users. Having a few if/else statements might be okay but when the program gets large, will be very hard to keep track of the statements without the '{' and '}'

Comment: @all: please don't forget that sometimes SO questions could be sometimes theoretical, for academic purposes, etc. I do agree that braces are essential for code readability except a few cases, but asking how Java behaves doesn't imply I'm going to write bad code (unless I want to submit a story to codinghorror.com)

Comment: @djechelon Dude, just wanted to convey a message regardign good programming practice... No offense intended at all. Regarding curiosity, we are all here just because we are curious. Your curiosity is always appreciated :)

Comment: @djechelon I never wanted to sound like I am giving instructions, still if you feel offended, I apologize

Comment: Still not a very good question. How useful is it to ask us to look up the specification for you?

Comment: @djechelon as your question was "according to the JLS..." you already knew where to find our answer!

Comment: @PrasadKharkar I was not offended, I just wanted to clarify that I didn't need instructions

Comment: @damo I believe that creating knowledge on SO is positive for the community: if another one has the same question he doesn't have to look through java docs but can find the straight answer through a Google search (being SO highly ranked)

Comment: I agree. I just don't think that it's particularly constructive to ask someone to simply cite the JLS or to ask a question that can easily be answered with a simple "try it yourself" test case. Google shouldn't be someone's first resource for a question like this. This could have been a much better question if was geared more towards _how_ Java resolves the ambiguity in your code snippet.

Comment: Well, I came to Google looking for this answer, and this was the first result, and I found my answer remarkably quickly. It certainly would have taken longer if I'd had to read through the JLS.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5):

> The Java programming language, like C and C++ and many programming languages before them, arbitrarily decrees that an else clause belongs to the innermost if to which it might possibly belong.

Answer (score 7):

Block 1 is correct, in if else situations with no brackets
the else is linked to the nearest if

```
if (condition 1)  
if (condition 2)
action 1;
else
action 2;
```

is the same as

```
if (condition 1)
    if (condition 2)
    action 1;
    else
    action 2;
```

also brackets are for the sake of understanding level, and ease. In larger if else statements, having no brackets makes error very common

Answer (score 4):

You can try it and find that the `else` applies to the inner `if`:

http://ideone.com/iBorYi

This is a good reason not to write code like this.  It's very hard to read and understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents for a better visual representation.

Everything inside braces will be completely ignored.

```
   if (false) {
        if (true)
            System.out.println("1");
        else
            System.out.println("2");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Block 1 is the right interpretation. The else always belongs the most recent 'if'.
(top of stack)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).