# Java if-if-else behavior

Tags: java, if-statement

I wrote a simple `if/else` in my code which worked fine.  Later I added another level of `if` under the first, and was baffled by its behavior.  Here's very simple code to recreate the situation:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean a = true;
    boolean b = false;

    if (a)
        if (b)
            System.out.println("a=true, b=true");
    else
        System.out.println("a=false");
}
```

It returns "`a=false`", even though `a` is true!

It turns out the `else` binds with the nearest `if`, although I have not found it documented anywhere, and eclipse does not highlight the mismatched indentation levels as an error (although it does correct it when formatting the file).

A very, very strong argument for using braces!

> Where is the binding order of `else`/`if` documented?

And as a challenge,

> Is there a way to make the above code do what the indentation makes you expect without adding braces?

Comment: one line of code don't need brace, else you need, otherwise how do you think it should work the way you expect. why would you think otherwise? your code in plain English tells to print a=false

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested if-else behaviour without braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172536/nested-if-else-behaviour-without-braces)

Comment: Jesus Christ!  Use braces!!

Comment: Yes, use braces.  This ain't python, not even jython.

Comment: In my defense I am not a Python coder (although very recently I started using it just to be hip like all you young guys with plaid shirts and beards), and I *always* use braces unless it's a one-liner, and most of the time even then.  So I started with a one liner, which later grew an else, and later got the extra if.  Yes, I should have added braces at that point.  The unexpected behavior was unexpected because Eclipse has trained me out of careful thinking about every character the way we did in the old days on punch cards.

Comment: @JeffSnider: Netbeans by defaults wraps single liner into block. In eclipse also I guess you can import code formatter to achieve this (not for sure, it's been awhile with eclipse).

Answer (score 19):

> Is there a way to make the above code do what the indentation makes you expect without adding braces?

No. Because Java is not Python, and compiler doesn't work based on what's on your mind. That is why you should always use braces.

Clearly the `else` is a part of the inner `if`, and hence the result is expected. This is evident from [JLS §14.5 - Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5)

Comment: _Because Java is not Python..._ A-ha!

Comment: This answer is incorrect, as demonstrated by the one from @Cruncher.

Comment: @JeffSnider Not sure what makes you think that anything mentioned in the answer is _incorrect_.  Surely you could come up with pathological ways to avoid braces but it'd turn the code really unreadable.

Comment: @devnull The question is "Is there any way to...", and the given answer is "No", which is false: two other answers give examples of how to do exactly what is asked.  That makes this an incorrect answer.

Comment: If you want to get pedantic, another way to make the code work is to write it in Python.  For the sake of clarity and convention I strongly recommend using braces.

Answer (score 11):

> Is there a way to make the above code do what the indentation makes
>   you expect without adding braces?

```
if (a)
    if (b)
        System.out.println("a=true, b=true");
    else;
else
    System.out.println("a=false");
```

`else;` will definitively finish the innermost if.

I would like to note that, if I ever came across this code in production, I would hunt through the commit logs until I found out who wrote it. This is absolutely an unacceptable thing to do. but it answers the quoted question

Answer (score 10):

It is clearly stated in [Language specification 14.5. Statements:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5)

> Java programming language suffers from the so-called "dangling else
>   problem,

Statements are thus grammatically divided into two categories: those that might end in an if statement that has no else clause (a "short if statement") and those that definitely do not.

Only statements that definitely do not end in a short if statement may appear as an immediate substatement before the keyword else in an if statement that does have an else clause.

Answer (score 4):

It *is* documented in [Section 14.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) of the Java Language Spec:

> The problem is that both the outer if statement and the inner if
>   statement might conceivably own the else clause. In this example, one
>   might surmise that the programmer intended the else clause to belong
>   to the outer if statement.
>
> The Java programming language, like C and C++ and many programming
>   languages before them, arbitrarily decrees that an else clause belongs
>   to the innermost if to which it might possibly belong. This rule is
>   captured by the following grammar:

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way to make the above code do what the indentation makes
>   you expect without adding braces?

I would go:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean a = true;
    boolean b = false;

    if (!a)
        System.out.println("a=false");   
    else if(b)
        System.out.println("a=true, b=true");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean a = true;
    boolean b = false;

    if (a && b)
        System.out.println("a=true, b=true");
    else if (!a)
        System.out.println("a=false");
}
```

Comment: This is strictly a less elegant version of @Liam's answer.

Comment: @Cruncher True, this is more clunky, however it made more sense in my head.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, best advice is to always use braces!

**Naturally, every else statement is attached to the nearest if-statement** and this is evident from [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5) and this is why your code behaves this way. The compiler cares nothing about indentation.. You can write your entire code on one line, it'd still work as long as its syntactically correct.

Also, if you *want the output you expected*, nesting an if-statement inside another if-statement (with no else-statement) is a primitive practice; this can simply be done with the `&&` operator like this:

```
if (a && b)
        System.out.println("a=true, b=true");
else
    System.out.println("a=false");
```

You'd have gotten your desired output. I hope this helps.. Merry coding!