# PHP nested else statement without braces

Tags: php

I am working on legacy code I have inherited and I have come across this code.

- This Code works!
- Ignore the variable names look at the **`{`** the first Condition opens but never closes the else has no open? it still works?
- Is it continuing on both or only one condition and if one which one?
- Why does it even work?

  ```
  foreach($bla as $foo) { 

     if(condition) {
     if(condition) {
      // Do Something
     }else
       continue;
     }

  }
  ```

My assumption is that the inner condition will be using the else? but I am only assuming that because of this answer: [Nested if-else behaviour without braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172536/nested-if-else-behaviour-without-braces) I cannot find a definitive answer for PHP

Comment: `Ignore the variable names look at the \`{\` the first Condition opens but never closes the else has no open? it still works?` Oh but it does close (second to the last closing `}`).

Comment: The key here is that [a *single* statement doesn't have to be wrapped in braces](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php). Your `continue;` line is equivalent to `{ continue; }`. The rest of your confusion is just down to the indentation, I'd assume. I personally recommend using braces around even a single statement, but that's probably still considered a religious matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may rephrase this code (with proper indentation usage):

```
foreach($bla as $foo) {   // FOREACH
   if(condition) {        // IF#1
      if(condition) {     // IF#2
          // Do Something
      } else continue;    // END IF#2
   }                      // END IF#1
}                         // END FOREACH
```

***Now answers on your questions:***

> Is it continuing on both or only one condition and if one which one?

It is `continue`ing only if nested [`if()`](http://php.net/if) (IF#2) statement condition evaluated to `false`.

> Why does it even work?

It works because [`if()`](http://php.net/if) **allows** syntax without brackets for simple operations. See example 1 at the manual. So nested [`if()`](http://php.net/if) closed exactly by `continue` operation with following delimiter `;`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the `else` applies to the inner condition. The code compiles because the `else` block has no opening brace, so the braces are still balanced. Here's the same code properly indented:

```
foreach($bla as $foo) { 
    if(condition) {
        if(condition) {
            // Do Something
        }
        else
            continue;
    }
}
```

Of course this is inconsistent and a very bad way to write this code.

Answer (score 2):

Surely it means that if the first IF condition is true, it will then go to the second IF condition.

So the second IF condition will only be read if the first one is true.

```
foreach($bla as $foo) { 

    if(condition) {
        if(condition) {
            // Do Something
        }else continue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the "else" (or if, for that matter) is a one-liner, it doesn't need braces. The "else" in question is continuing the inner "if".