# The rules of Nested IF conditional statements without using curly braces

Tags: java, c++

This might be an extremely beginner question given that I have about 2 years of programming experience already, however something always bothered me with nested IF conditional statements and how they work without having curly braces on them.

I've always used the braces as to keep my coding organized. For example like this.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int x = 9;
    int y = 8;
    int z = 7; 
    if (x > 9)
    {
        if (y > 8)
        {
            System.out.println("x > 9 and y > 8");
        }
    }
    else if (z >= 7)
    {
        System.out.println("x <= 9 and z >= 7");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("x <= 9 and z < 7");
    }
}
```

I've always used this pattern as it has always worked for me.

However, why is it that something written in this format doesn't work the same way?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int x = 9;
    int y = 8;
    int z = 7; 
    if (x > 9)
        if (y > 8)
            System.out.println("x > 9 and y > 8");
    else if (z >= 7)
        System.out.println("x <= 9 and z >= 7");
    else 
        System.out.println("x <= 9 and z < 7");
}
```

The first code would print out x <= 9 and z >= 7, but the second code would print nothing. (I'm assuming that the else if and else statements are inside the initial if statement).

In other words, what are the rules in how the compiler tests the conditional statements when no curly braces take place like the example above? I've tried looking for information online, but I can't seem to find information and/or I don't know how to specifically call this problem in order to research my doubts.

Comment: good idea to use curly braces eh.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested if-else behaviour without braces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172536/nested-if-else-behaviour-without-braces)

Comment: Based on the first `;` if there are no Curly braces..

Comment: @user1354678 - care to post an answer supporting your comment?

Answer (score 1):

On second if I put braces on it, It will be like this to the compiler. Because `else if` or `else` finds immediate `if`.

```
if (x > 9) {
        if (y > 8){
            System.out.println("x > 9 and y > 8");
        }else if (z >= 7) {
            System.out.println("x <= 9 and z >= 7");
        }else {
            System.out.println("x <= 9 and z < 7");
        }
}
```

If you have to replicate you should put at least one braces like:

```
if (x > 9) {
        if (y > 8)
            System.out.println("x > 9 and y > 8");
        else if (z >= 7)
            System.out.println("x <= 9 and z >= 7");
}else 
    System.out.println("x <= 9 and z < 7");
```

Now, Last else is off first if statement for sure.

Comment: I see. So basically the "else if" and the "else" would be a part of the most recent if?

Comment: Yes, After all compiler does not understand your business logic. You have to do it right ;)

Comment: Interesting. So what would be the case if the last "else" has not just one statement, but two statements? Would that second statement no longer be a part of the if conditional statements?

Comment: Every else should have its if, but it is not necessary to have else for every if. So you cannot have else all alone. i.e. Else executes if "if" statement fails. There is no purpose of else without if. Take a real life scenario

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not care about indentation. An `else` clause is always associated with the *last* `if` that doesn't already have an `else`. This:

```
if (x > 9)
    if (y > 8)
        System.out.println("x > 9 and y > 8");
else if (z >= 7)
    System.out.println("x <= 9 and z >= 7");
else 
    System.out.println("x <= 9 and z < 7");
```

is the same as this:

```
if (x > 9)
{
    if (y > 8)
    {
        System.out.println("x > 9 and y > 8");
    }
    else
    {
        if (z >= 7)
        {
            System.out.println("x <= 9 and z >= 7");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("x <= 9 and z < 7");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, notice that `else if(...) ...` really just means `else {if(...) {...}}` - it's a combination of `else` and `if`, not a special feature.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a matter of curly braces, it's a matter of how you've formatted your code.  Whitespace doesn't matter in Java (or C++.)

So while you've written this:

```
if (x > 9)
    if (y > 8)
        System.out.println("x > 9 and y > 8");
else if (z >= 7)
    System.out.println("x <= 9 and z >= 7");
else 
    System.out.println("x <= 9 and z < 7");
```

That doesn't mean it's equivalent to your original code.  To illustrate why, here's how this code would be more reasonably formatted:

```
if (x > 9)
    if (y > 8)
        System.out.println("x > 9 and y > 8");
    else if (z >= 7)
        System.out.println("x <= 9 and z >= 7");
    else 
        System.out.println("x <= 9 and z < 7");
```

I hope that illustrates what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces are, essentially, to keep the compiler on track. If you only have 1 if, and 1 else, such as:

```
 if (x < 3)
    // some code here
 else
    // something else here
```

When you do math problems in real life, order of operations tells you to do what's in the parentheses first, no? The curly brackets are a grouping symbol used to denote what order of operations the compiler is to take.