# Curly braces in if-else blocks

Tags: java, if-statement, curly-braces

I'm programming in java and I happened to find myself with this:

```
if(nodo == null) return null;
    else if(nodo.izquierda!=null && nodo.derecha==null)
        return nodo.izquierda;
    else if(nodo.izquierda==null && nodo.derecha!=null)
        return nodo.derecha;
    else return null; // si ambos hijos son nulos o no nulos
```

My question is: Is it the same to write that as:

```
if(nodo == null) 
    return null;
else {
    if(nodo.izquierda!=null && nodo.derecha==null)
        return nodo.izquierda;
    else {
        if(nodo.izquierda==null && nodo.derecha!=null)
              return nodo.derecha;
        else return null; // si ambos hijos son nulos o no nulos
    }
 }
```

More than anything I'm confused by how to use the curly braces with if-else blocks. Is it necesary to use curly braces?

For example:

```
if (something)
     if (something else)
     ...
     else (blah blah)
```

Is the same that:

```
if (something)
{
     if (something else)
     ...
     else (blah blah)
}
```

Comment: Curly braces are not required with `if` statements.  If they are not present, the next argument, and only the next argument, will be used if the clause if true.  The same is true for your else statement.  If there are no brackets, then only the very next statement is part of the else clause, nothing else will be considered part of your `if...else...` statement

Comment: Curly brackets are there to encapsulate a block of code. It is generally a good idea to use brackets with proper indentation so that it is clear to the reader what code belongs where. Not using curly brackets for single line if statements may induce pride at the 2 or 3 bytes saved, however I have found it to be one of the easiest ways to introduce bugs in code due to the ease with which a small typing error can change large amounts of logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> For example:
>
> ```
> if (something)
>       if (something else)
>       ...
>       else (blah blah)
> ```
>
> Is the same that:
>
> ```
>  if (something)
>    {
>       if (something else)
>       ...
>       else (blah blah)
>    }
> ```

In this case, yes, they're the same, but the former is harder to read than the latter. I recommend using braces always, even for blocks of code made of a single line.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 last statements execute the same; omitting the braces is legal but is not recommended.

If the braces are omitted for an `else if`, the `else if` always belongs to the **innermost** `if` statement.
 [REFERENCE: Link to the IF ELSE behavior if braces are Omitted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172536/nested-if-else-behaviour-without-braces)

This URL: [Link to Study of Code with Braces Omitted](http://java.dzone.com/news/omitting-braces-not-just-a-mat)  contains the result of an analysis and states that projects with code that omits braces for "if statements" are more likely to have bugs.

**If a developer intentionally omits the braces (which is legal), the next developer looking at the code without braces will have to mentally "parse" each else if and match the else if to the closest if statement.**  It is much easier to match `if` to `else if` and `else`  when there are braces that are indent-aligned.

The code is easiest to read when code inside the braces in a top-level if statement is indented 4 spaces, and code in a second-level if statement is indented 8 spaces, as in:

```
if (var1 == 1) {
    action1();
}
else if (var1 == 2) {
    action2();
}
else if (var1 == 3) {

    if (var2 == 1) {
        action31();
    }
    else if (var2 == 2) {
        action32();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For Java, curly braces are optional for if-else statements. As Jared stated, only the next statement will be executed when curly braces are omitted.

Generally the braces help with organization and readability of the code, so they commonly will be used.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Is it the same to write that as:

The fact that you need to ask is a very good reason to use the braces. There are always two audiences for code, a compiler and any human who may need to read and reason about the code, including your own future self.

Often, braces will be unnecessary for the compiler, but enhance readability for the other audience.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(nodo != null)
    if(nodo.izquierda != null && nodo.derecha == null)
        return nodo.izquierda;
    else if(nodo.izquierda == null && nodo.derecha != null)
        return nodo.derecha;
return null;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.